# How do i handle a Repository with rx-java

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming

Hello,
I'm wondering how to handle the deletion from a Repository with java-rx.
Here is a quick overview of my Domain.

My Businessobject:

```
public class MyObject{
  public boolean isActive();
  public boolean isSelected();
}
```

Only one Object can be active or selected at a time.

The Repository:

```
public interface Repository{
 Observable<MyObject> get();
 void delete(MyObject obj); //do i really need this?
}
```

Now i want to delete Objectes under certain circumstances:

```
-Delete selected object only if more than 1 Object is in Repository  
-if selected object == acvtive we have to set another object active
```

Here is the implementation of my repository like I thought it can be:

```
public class RepositoryImpl implements Repository{
private void List<MyObject> myObjects;

@Override
public Observable<MyObject> get(){
    if(myObjects != null) return Observable.from(myObjects);
    return Observable.create((Observable.OnSubscribe<MyObject> subscriber -> {
        try{
            myObjects = gson.fromJson(...);
            for(MyObject obj : myObjects){
                subscriber.onNext(obj);
            }
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }catch(Exception e){
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
    }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

}

@Override
void delete(MyObject obj){
    //we assume myObjects is filled
    if(myObjects.size < 2) return;
    boolean wasActive = false;
    if(obj.isActive()){
        wasActive = true;
    }
    myObjects.remove(obj);
    MyObject first = myObjects.get(0);
    first.setActive(wasActive);
    first.setSelected(true);
}
```

So the first question is, do I have to implement a delete function in the repository or is there a fancy way to handle deletion with the stream i get from the get method.

And the second one is, is there an easy way to notify the UI (RecyclerView) about the change in the repository (I work with MVP and not with bindings)?

Comment: You should not share state outside of the stream context. In your case you are sharing myObjects. You should always parse from json. After the get() is correct you have to see how you properly cache in RX. Your delete seems to me to be really cache eviction.

Comment: Nothing wrong with `Observable<Void> delete(...)`